# MySQL Group by category limit N from each category

Tags: php, mysql

TABLE

```
id       title        category
```

---

```
1        hello1          1
2        hello2          2
3        hello3          1
```

Query

```
select  *
from    videos
where   category in
        (
        select  category
        from    videos
        group by 
               category
        having 
               count(*) < 3
ORDER BY RAND()
        )
```

my goal is to get 2 titles from each category in a random order
also I want to fetch records in this manner

```
category1
title1
title2
```

---

```
category2
title1
title2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below query gives no more than two random rows from each category:

```
SELECT title, category
FROM (
  SELECT v.*,
     if( category = @last_cat,
         if( @last_cat:=category, @x:=@x+1,@x:=@x+1),
         if( @last_cat:=category, @x:=0,@x:=0)
     ) x
  FROM (SELECT @last_cat:=-9876, @x:=-91234) x,
       (SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY category, rand()) v
) x
WHERE x < 2
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59cf9/8

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Please try this updated query  (**SQL Fiddle** - **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de35bb/9**):

```
select  videos.*
from    videos
where   
    (
        select  COUNT(vid.id)
        from    videos AS vid
        WHERE videos.category = vid.category
    ) <= 2
ORDER BY
  videos.category, RAND()
```

I've managed to find the solution on SO here: 
**[Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)**
in which answer points to the article 
**[How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)**
where author describes a few techniques of performing such task.
The above query was built upon an example provided in the second article, but there are other forms of solving this problem.

Comment: this actually doesn't do any good :( 
the problem is I can't think of how to do this. the algorithm is more difficult than the coding lol

Comment: Please find the working (at least I thought so) example here **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d46d4/5** . Maybe you could edit your answer to show the attempt in PHP code for performing the task to the end?

Comment: it's weird, it's working fine on the link you gave me with exact same code!

Comment: The code in the answer along with the one in SQL Fiddle differs only slightly from the one you gave as your attempt - the differences are: `ORDER BY` is performed in the topmost query ; `ORDER BY category,` was added to get the results you marked as expected. So I think you were on a good path for the solution.

Comment: oh i get it, it's grabbing titles with less than 3 cats so if you only add one more car '1' it will not work

Comment: must say that for now I have no other idea how to build the query - hope you'll find the solution - I'll continue to try also. Regards.

Comment: thanks btw, i just need to plan it on piece of paper it's too late now